# Asking a question about CnosDB subscription management

Tags: cnosdb

Please take a look at the SQL：

```
oceanic_station ❯ CREATE SUBSCRIPTION test1 ON oceanic_station  DESTINATIONS ALL "127.0.0.1:8913";
Query took 0.023 seconds.
```

When I added an existing node, the addition was successful.
please watch the following part

```
oceanic_station ❯ ALTER SUBSCRIPTION test ON public DESTINATIONS ALL "127.0.0.1:8913" "127.0.0.1:8915";
Query took 0.012 seconds.
oceanic_station ❯ SHOW SUBSCRIPTION ON public;
+--------------+-------------------------------+------+
| SUBSCRIPTION | DESTINATIONS                  | MODE |
+--------------+-------------------------------+------+
| test         | 127.0.0.1:8913,127.0.0.1:8915 | ALL  |
+--------------+-------------------------------+------+
```

But the 127.0.0.1:8915 node is a non-existent node, and it was still successfully added. Could there be any problems with this?